# Expansion of $(a+b+c+d+e+....)^n$, but with all coefficients equal to 1.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, symmetric-polynomials, dynamic-programming

I'm looking for a formula to calculate the sum of $(a+b+c+d+...)^n$ but with coefficients equal to 1.
For example in $(a+b+c)^2$. I want the sum of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + bc + ca$. And for $(a+b+c+d)^3$,
I want the sum of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + a^2b + a^2c + b^2a + b^2c + c^2a + c^2b + abc$.
Similarly, I want the sum of expansion of $(a+b+c+d+e+....)^n$ with coefficient equal to 1.
I tried to find the pattern by expanding the $(a+b+c)^2$. And I found that its formula is $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ + $\frac{((a+b+c)^2 - a^2-b^2-c^2)}{2}$. This works for the power of 2. But fails on other powers.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: @PeterForeman I need the sum where n can be 1e18. So iterative method will fail.

Comment: The actual question is to find sum of the product of powers of k numbers where sum of the powers of the numbers is equal to n. For example, if the numbers are a,b,c and n is 2,
the sum should be $a^2b^0c^0+a^0b^2c^0+a^0b^0c^2+a^1b^1c^0+a^1b^0c^1+a^0b^1c^1$

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527907/homogeneous-products-of-variables/3529832#3529832)?  Is this a formula you seek $$\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1^{n+k-1}&x_2^{n+k-1}&\cdots &x_k^{n+k-1}\\
x_1^{k-2}&x_2^{k-2}&\cdots &x_k^{k-2}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_k\\1&1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}}{\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1^{k-1}&x_2^{k-1}&\cdots &x_k^{k-1}\\
x_1^{k-2}&x_2^{k-2}&\cdots &x_k^{k-2}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_k\\1&1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}}?$$

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Thanks, this formula is working :$ \frac {{a^{n+2}(b-c)}+{b^{n+2}(c-a)}+{c^{n+2}(a-b)}} {{a^2(b-c)}+{b^2(c-a)}+{c^2(a-b)}}$. But, what will change if we have a,b,c,d ?

Comment: Did you look at my comment above (with determinant and all)?

Comment: @Anonyme  That is not what the OP wants.  The OP wants the sum of all the degree-$n$ monomials in $k$ variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$, each monomial having coefficient $1$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Yes, I looked at the solution, but my problem is that, k can be 1e18, so finding determinant is impossible. But number of terms are small (around 10). So, the question has the formula for 3 terms, but I was looking for the formula for 10 terms.

Comment: So, what is big?  $k$ or $n$?  The number of terms is $k$ in the determinant above, and $n$ is the degree.  If the number of terms is small, then finding the determinant is easy.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool, Okay I got it, so, the maximum size of determinant will k*k. It will work. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $k$ variables $x_1, \ldots, x_k$, let $P_n(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ be the sum of all monomials over them for degree $n$.

$$P_n(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{\sum_{j=1}^{k} e_j = n} \prod_{j=1}^k x_j^{e_j}, \quad\text{where}\quad e_1,\ldots,e_k \in \mathbb{N}$$

Multiply by $s^n$ and sum over $n$, we find

$$\begin{align}
P(s) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n P_n(\cdots)
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\sum_{j=1}^{k} e_j = n} \prod_{j=1}^k (sx_j)^{e_j}\\
&= \sum_{e_1=0}^\infty\cdots\sum_{e_k=0}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^k (sx_j)^{e_j}
= \prod_{j=1}^k \sum_{e_j=0}^\infty (sx_j)^{e_j}\\
&= \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1 - s x_j}\end{align}$$

Apply partial fraction decomposition to RHS, we obtain

$$P(s) = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1-sx_j} \prod_{\ell=1,\ne j}^k \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x_\ell}{x_j}}
= \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{x_j^{k-1}}{1-s x_j}\prod_{\ell=1,\ne j}^k \frac1{x_j - x_\ell}$$
Expand both sides and compare coefficients of $s^n$, we can represent $P_n$ as a sum of $k$ rational functions.

$$P_n(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \sum_{j=1}^k x_j^{n+k-1}\prod_{\ell=1,\ne j}^k \frac{1}{x_j - x_\ell}$$

Comment: How to deal with the variables that are same. For eg. suppose variables are 1,1,1, and the degree is 1. I want the answer to be 3, like: $1^11^01^0 + 1^01^11^0 + 1^01^01^1$.

Comment: @JazibKhan If some specific set of variables is the same, one need to go back to the product $\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1 - s x_j}$ and works out corresponding partial fraction decomposition, I don't think there is any simple formula which works for all cases. If all variable is the same, then the product reduces to $\frac{1}{(1-sx)^k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{n} (sx)^n$.