# Multinomial sum?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to find the given sum modulo prime

Given n integers and a number $D$ you have to calculate $(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^D$  but the twist here is that there coefficient should not be considered in sum ;

e.g  $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$;

But , **required sum is $a^2 + b^2 + ab$;**

e.g  $(2+6+7)^2=15^2=225$

But , **required sum is : $2^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 6\cdot7 + 2\cdot7 + 2\cdot6 = 157$**

**Constraints :**

$N\le5000$ (elements where each element $\le10^5$)

$D\le10^{18}$; (Power)

**Any hint will be helpful :)**

Comment: So you want the number of terms? Are you familiar with [identical balls in distinct bins](https://brilliant.org/wiki/identical-objects-into-distinct-bins/)/

Comment: I dont want number of terms but sum of terms without considering  their coefficient.  Check my edited comment .

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Comment: Your question seems quite similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618639/expansion-of-abcde-n-but-with-all-coefficients-equal-to-1.

Comment: The post is similar but the answers does not mention a way to tackle the situation if some variables are equal