# Homogeneous Polynomials and Euler's Theorem

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, partial-derivative

If $H\left[n\right]$ is the sum of the homogeneous products of $n$ dimensions of $x,\:y,\:z$ prove: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(H\left[n\right]\right)+\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(H\left[n\right]\right)+\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:z}\left(H\left[n\right]\right)\:=\:\left(n+2\right)H\left[n-1\right]$

I found this question which seems to be related but I can't figure out how to take it from there:
[Homogeneous products of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527907/homogeneous-products-of-variables)

I wrote down the terms of the LHS as well but I couldn't see how that simplifies to anything in terms of $H\left[n\right]$. Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The terms of the left side are homogenous of degree $n-1.$ If $i+j+k=n-1$ then the terms that contribute to $x^iy^jz^k$ on the left side are:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^{i+1}y^jz^k)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^iy^{j+1}z^k)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x^iy^jz^{k+1})$$

Compute.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the RHS. Forgive me if this is a stupid question but is $\left(^{i+1}^j^k\right)\:=\left(^i^{j+1}^k\right)\:=\:\left(^i^j^{k+1}\right)\:=\:H\left[n\right]$ correct?